# How to create Windows 10 Settings app (Immersive Control Panel) applet?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10, controlpanel

Following the instructions given on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144185(v=vs.85).aspx) I was able to create a Windows Control Panel applet (classic control Panel).

The "HALO WORLD" applet in the following image has been created by me.

[image: Sample control Panel applet]

How can I do the same for Windows 10 Settings App (Immersive Control Panel) ?
That is I want such an entry on the following screen.
[image: Windows 10 Settings app]

I am willing to write a UWP app if need be.

Comment: AFAIK, There is no such way to have your own items in the Settings App.

Comment: I discovered that there is a file - `C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\Settings\AllSystemSettings_{253E530E-387D-4BC2-959D-E6F86122E5F2}.xml` which seems to maintain a database of all settings in the app. Only if somehow I could get to add my entry to this file.

Comment: Have you tried manually editing that file to see if it actually works?

Comment: I am trying to understand its structure.

Comment: @Martin's response is correct; there is no supported way of doing this. Is there a missing feature in Windows you're trying to provide? If so, have you used the Feedback Hub to submit your bug / feature request?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to modify the Settings app this way.

However, why would want to do so? The rule of thumb is settings should be integrated in the app itself, which is also more convenient for the user and easier for you to manage. `NavigationView` control itself has even an integrated settings menu item, as it is such a common requirement of developers.

Comment: The settings in the new Settings Apps have an associated URI scheme.
There is a URI scheme called `ms-settings:extras` which hints that it may be possible to host more (custom) URI.
That's what got me thinking of an attempt to customize settings app, as in *.cpl days.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#extras